# Capturing the click event of a Like button

Tags: javascript, facebook, sdk, facebook-like

I'm trying to subscribe to the Like button click.  Here's the code I have:

```
<body>

<!-- Facebook Like Button with your App ID  -->
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=349467237487892";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
  function(response) {
    alert('You liked the URL: ' + response);
  }
);
```

The Like button appears and works ok but I don't get the alert when it's clicked.  Does anyone see the problem?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to attach the event after the JS SDK has had a chance to load. Use fbAsyncInit to do this.

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {

  FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
       alert('You liked the URL: ' + response);
  });
};
```

Comment: Yes, that was it.  Thanks. But where is window.fbAsyncInit documented?  A search of the FaceBook developer's site doesn't find anything and my "Facebook Application Development for Dummies" book doesn't have anything on it.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell from the api you need to subscribe to the edge.create event - example from api documentation.

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
    function(response) {
        alert('You liked the URL: ' + response);
    }
);
```

You can read more about FB event subscription [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/).

Comment: How do you capture "follow" event?