# Capturing the -REAL-click event of a Like button

Tags: javascript, facebook

As answered on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8888941/capturing-the-click-event-of-a-like-button), you can detect the like action using:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {

  FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
       alert('You liked the URL: ' + response);
  });
};
```

As I said, you can detect the *like action*, so actually you are waiting for a callback from the facebook servers. This callback could take from 2 to 5 seconds, I will like to detect the actual click on the like button, so i can bind a function to it and fire it right away.

No jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not possible because the like button is inside an iframe.

This is a limitation at the browser level for obvious security reason.

Comment: Im using the non iframe solution

Comment: Every techniques create a iframe behind the scene (except the URL of course). Check your page code after javascript been executed.