# How can I make a button change its position after being clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I make a button change its position after being clicked like this [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/LJHQW/) but instead of the active parameter I would like it to be at `margin-left:50px;` definitely after clicked

HTML

```
<div class="button">
    <button type="fb-like">Fb-Like</button>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.button:active {
    margin-left:50px;
}
/* But with a on clicked parameter instead of active */
```

Comment: Added JavaScript tag; `onClick` functionality is not feasible with CSS. There are things like the `:target` hack that will achieve this, but they are not dependable/semantic.

Comment: It does appear, however, that similar functionality will be [added to HTML](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#the-menu-element) in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use JavaScript:

```
var d = document.getElementById("button");
d.addEventListener('click',function(){
    d.className = d.className + " move";
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LJHQW/3/

Or, if you're **already** using jQuery:

```
$('.button').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('move');
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LJHQW/1/

Comment: What am I doing wrong here @Mooseman ? jsfiddle.net/qUjDa The button only moves if I click on the right side of it, or below it

Comment: @Chun **Events don't bubble from inside an `iframe`.** Clicking to the right or below is outside of the `iframe` and inside `.button`, thus why it works.

Comment: So how can I do this? I've been trying for hours but I don't know how to make a fb button do that :\

Comment: @Chun Use the Facebook API as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8889289/1234256).

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/LJHQW/2/

JavaScript:

```
/* Toggles the style class on click */

$("button").click(function() {
    $(".button").toggleClass("buttonLeft");
});
```

CSS:

```
.buttonLeft {margin-left:50px;} /* But with a on clicked parameter instead of active */
```

Comment: This won't move the button definitly, if the user clicks again, it will come back to original position

Comment: That's not exactly javascript, it's jQuery and there's no jQuery tag in question....

Comment: @TilwinJoy to be fair, there wasn't a JavaScript tag to begin with, either. So this might be a case of OP just not knowing what he needs, but would be willing to consider multiple options.

Comment: jQuery is a JavaScript library. So it is a JavaScript based solution using jQuery.  Here's is a fiddle that changes it indefinitely:  http://jsfiddle.net/LJHQW/4/