# How to make button randomly change position when clicked

Tags: javascript, css, dom

When I click on the button, I would like the position of the button to change to a random location.

Here is what I have tried:

```js
var b = document.querySelector("button");
b.addEventListener("click",change);
var i = Math.floor(Math.random()*500)+1;
var j = Math.floor(Math.random()*500)+1;
function change()
{
    b.style.left = i+"px";
    b.style.top = j+"px";
}
```

```css
button{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
    position: absoulte;
}
```

```html
<button>
Hello World
</button>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24638192/how-can-i-make-a-button-change-its-position-after-being-clicked, possible duplicate

Comment: You seem to be setting values for i and j only once. If you want them to change on each click they need to be inside the function change. You have mistyped absolute also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define `i` and `j` inside `change()` method so that it can be randomly updated when button is clicked.

Also, there is a typo in your code `position: absoulte` which should be corrected to *`absolute`*

```js
var b = document.querySelector("button");
b.addEventListener("click",change);
function change()
{
    var i = Math.floor(Math.random()*500)+1;
    var j = Math.floor(Math.random()*500)+1;
    b.style.left = i+"px";
    b.style.top = j+"px";
}
```

```css
button{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<button>abc</button>
```

Comment: Also mention that you corrected `absolute`

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to move the random calculation inside the `change()` function.

To keep the element within it's containing element you can use [`getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect). (And account for the size of the button to avoid overlaps on the right and bottom using the same.)

```js
const c = document.querySelector(".container");
const b = document.querySelector("button");

function change() {
  const
    { width: cWidth, height: cHeight } = c.getBoundingClientRect(),
    { width: bWidth, height: bHeight } = b.getBoundingClientRect(),
    i = Math.floor(Math.random() * (cWidth - bWidth)) + 1,
    j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (cHeight - bHeight)) + 1;

  b.style.left = i + "px";
  b.style.top = j + "px";
}

b.addEventListener("click", change);
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 50vh;
  width: 50vw;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

button{
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <button type='button' id='shifty'>Click</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML :-

```
<body>
 <div class="ctr">
   <button class="button" id="movingbutton">Button</button>
 </div>
</body>
```

CSS:-

```
 #movingbutton{
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        display: block;
           position: absolute;
        left : 20px;
    top : 50px;
    }
    body{
      width : 100%;
    }
    .ctr{
      width : 100%;
    height : 100%;
    }
```

JS:-

```
       var b = document.querySelector("#movingbutton");
b.addEventListener("click",change);

function change()
{
let i =Math.abs(Math.floor(Math.random()*window.innerWidth-55))
let j = Math.abs(Math.floor(Math.random()*window.innerHeight-21));
console.log('here' , i ,j , b.style.left , b.style.top);
    b.style.left = i+'px';
    b.style.top = j + "px";
}
```

If you want you can check here: [Live example link](https://jsfiddle.net/mak9L4p1/15/)

You need to add one more condition if that button goes outside window.innerWidth and window.innerHeight

Answer (score 0):

With this element, you cannot change your random position.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

If you want to move randomly a button you can use simple .bind(). You can also move button when your mouse is moving in button area(without clicking it) .
Here are both codes:

> Code for click

```js
var b = document.querySelector("#movingbutton");
b.addEventListener("click",change);

function change()
{
let i = Math.floor(Math.random()*500)+1;
let j = Math.floor(Math.random()*500)+1;
console.log('here' , i ,j , b.style.left , b.style.top);
    b.style.left = i+'px';
    b.style.top = j + "px";
}
```

```css
#movingbutton{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
       position: absolute;
    left : 20px;
top : 50px;
}
body{
  width : 100%;
}
.ctr{
  width : 100%;
height : 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="ctr">
<button class="button" id="movingbutton">Button</button>

</div>
</body>
```

> Code for mousemove

```js
var b = document.querySelector("#movingbutton");
b.addEventListener("mousemove",change);

function change()
{
let i = Math.floor(Math.random()*500)+1;
let j = Math.floor(Math.random()*500)+1;
console.log('here' , i ,j , b.style.left , b.style.top);
    b.style.left = i+'px';
    b.style.top = j + "px";
}
```

```css
#movingbutton{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
       position: absolute;
    left : 20px;
top : 50px;
}
body{
  width : 100%;
}
.ctr{
  width : 100%;
height : 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="ctr">
<button class="button" id="movingbutton">Button</button>

</div>
</body>
```